# AWS SDK version upgrade throws : ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError for SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-ssm

We have recently upgraded AWS SDK version to **1.11.913** but it (SSM) now throws below error. What am I doing wrong ?

> ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN:
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldErrorjava.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
> ENDPOINT_OVERRIDDEN   at
> com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.executeGetParameter(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:5859)   at
> com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.getParameter(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:5841)  at
> com.ritefit.common.utils.RDSHelper.getValueFromSSM(RDSHelper.java:63)

Comment: Can you please add the localstack ssm service via the java aws sdk in your question?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this ??

Comment: No, had to revert the changes to older version, where I do not get this issue anymore.